# Obtaining a reference to a Snapshot. Google Play Games Services Saved Games

Tags: google-play-games

```
       private PendingResult<Snapshots.CommitSnapshotResult> writeSnapshot(Snapshot snapshot,
                byte[] data, Bitmap coverImage, String desc) {

            // Set the data payload for the snapshot
            snapshot.getSnapshotContents().writeBytes(data);

            // Create the change operation
            SnapshotMetadataChange metadataChange = new SnapshotMetadataChange.Builder()
                    .setCoverImage(coverImage)
                    .setDescription(desc)
                    .build();

            // Commit the operation
            return Games.Snapshots.commitAndClose(mGoogleApiClient, snapshot, metadataChange);
        }
```

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames

The docs say that a reference to a Snapshot has to be obtained before calling writeSnaphot. Since snapshot is an interface it can't be created with new.

How to obtain a reference to a Snapshot?

Thank You!

P.S. I see that there is a way to obtain a reference by opening an existing saved game by name however the reference I would like to obtain is for a new Snapshot there are currently no existing snapshots so using the load function probably will not succeed in writing a new snapshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call open with a filename that does not exist to create a new snapshot.  This snippet uses .await() on the result from open, so you'll need to call it from an AsyncTask or some other non-UI thread. (see https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames for more details):

```
private PendingResult<Snapshots.CommitSnapshotResult> writeSnapshot(String newSnapshotFilename,
       byte[] data, Bitmap coverImage, String desc) {

Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result =
   Games.Snapshots.open(mGoogleApiClient, newSnapshotFilename, true).await();
// Check the result of the open operation
  if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
    Snapshot snapshot = result.getSnapshot();
    snapshot.getSnapshotContents().writeBytes(data);

    // Create the change operation
    SnapshotMetadataChange metadataChange = new
           SnapshotMetadataChange.Builder()
                .setCoverImage(coverImage)
                .setDescription(desc)
                .build();

    // Commit the operation
   return Games.Snapshots.commitAndClose(mGoogleApiClient, snapshot, metadataChange);
   }
   return null;
}
```