# Saving to Google Play Cloud Save Automatically

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, google-cloud-save

**BACKGROUND**
I'm working on an [android game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.regulusstudio.kitchensaga) that has been published on Google Play Store.
And now I'm planning to add Cloud Save feature as an update.
*(FYI: I'm using Unity and [Play Games plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity))*

**PROBLEM**
After hours of research and experiment, I'm currently stuck on how to save the game automatically.

My game is a collection of mini games where a player can keep playing until he runs out of lives.
I want the save to happen automatically at the time the player loses.

According to the plugin, this is how I save to the cloud:

```
public void SaveGame (ISavedGameMetadata game, byte[] savedData) {
    /* code omitted */
    savedGameClient.CommitUpdate(game, updatedMetadata, savedData, OnSavedGameWritten);
}
```

I need 2 parameters for the function `SaveGame`, the 1st one is the meta data, then the 2nd one is the data itself.

Everywhere I search (even in Google), I cannot find a way to generate the meta data automatically.
Based on my research, I can get the meta data from the function below:

```
void ShowSelectUI() {
    uint maxNumToDisplay = 5;
    bool allowCreateNew = true;
    bool allowDelete = true;

    // I will need to call this function first
    // This will display a dialog to the player
    // The player will need to create a new save manually afterwards
    ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
    savedGameClient.ShowSelectSavedGameUI("Select saved game",
                                          maxNumToDisplay,
                                          allowCreateNew,
                                          allowDelete,
                                          OnSavedGameSelected);
}


public void OnSavedGameSelected (SelectUIStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) {
    // And then from the callback function I get the meta data
    // (ISavedGameMetadata game)

    if (status == SelectUIStatus.SavedGameSelected) {
        // handle selected game save
    } else {
        // handle cancel or error
    }
}
```

This way user will need to open up a dialog and then create a new save by himself.
That can't happen in my game, as I need to save every time the player loses.

**REFERENCE**
I know that it should be possible, a game called [Get Bigger! Mola](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.molamola.molamolajump) could save the progress each time the player loses without opening up a save dialog.

**QUESTION**
Can anyone give me any clues about this?
I have spent my entire day searching without an answer...
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I am having the same problem. I'm positive there must be a way to do it, as a lot of games allow cloud saving based on google account, but I can't seem to find anything on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969656/obtaining-a-reference-to-a-snapshot-google-play-games-services-saved-games), you can open a new snapshot without having to select one from a list, just specify the filename, if it exist, it will use it, otherwise it will create a new one.

Something like this:

```
        ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
    savedGameClient.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(filename, DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
        ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime, delegate(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata metadata) {
            // your code here ....
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally am not familiar with the asset you try to save the stats with.
However, I did use this asset [Stan's Native](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10825) which I personally can recommend.

If you want something else for free, there's these links, [Search Native](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/android%20native)

anyway, you should check Google Tutorials about working with theie cloud, there's a lot of information, on the Android site, that doesn't involve Unity. [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/building-connectivity.html)